# Struct Literals in Golang

Tags: struct, go

In case of Struct Literals in Go,

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    p = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    q = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
    r = Vertex{X: 1, Y: 2}
)
```

The values for p, q and r are `{1 2} &{1 2} {1 2}`

What is the difference between the initialisation methods of the above three variables ? How are the variables p, q and r different ?

Comment: the only difference is that q is a pointer and not an instance. other than that the differences are only syntactic.

Comment: Thank You. So a Struct Literal is just a fixed value embedded in the source code, just like a normal literal ?

Comment: @john. There are important differences. Specifically, you can't make a const struct.

Comment: Thank You, You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`q` is a pointer to a struct allocated on the heap. The others are identical, and allocated on the stack. Whether you list the field names is purely for readability, and I suggest doing so whenever possible.

Comment: I don't think `q` is guaranteed to be on the heap, Go does rudimentary escape analysis and it may just end up being a pointer to somewhere else on the stack. (In fact, if it doesn't affect the program semantics at all, I think the compiler may be permitted to outright make it a value).

Comment: @Jsor: Actually, I know the other way is true for sure. `p` and `r` might be on the heap if escape analysis requires it. Probably the better distinction to make is how much time is needed to make the copy in `x := p` versus `y := q`.